# How to get SharePoint image without download to PC in C#

Tags: development

I have to get some image data from SharePoint library in my server side console app.

However, i only find the some download to PC solution in internet, so how get the image directly.

my code

```
foreach(SPListItem item in docLib.Items)
{
  // Access the file
  SPFile file = item.File;
  if(file != null)
  {
    // retrieve the file as a byte array
    byte[] bArray = file.OpenBinary();
    string filePath = Path.Combine("c:\\temp", file.Name);
    //open the file stream and write the file
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
      fs.Write(bArray, 0, bArray.Length);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bArray)
      Image myImage = Image.FromStream(ms); // i get my image now, but i have to download it to PC first.
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What image data do you need?

Comment: @JussiPalo the data that i can , for example, use `myImage.Save(@"C:\Users\HIHI\Downloads\asd.TIFF", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved it by using following code.Hope it will help you.

```
      public static string GetImageBinary(SPWeb web, string name)
      {
        string Logo = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb)
                    {
                        SPList spList = rootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.LISTNAME_SITEASSESTS);
                        if (spList != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /><Value Type='Text'>" + name + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                            SPListItemCollection files = spList.GetItems(query);

                            if (files.Count > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] image = files[0].File.OpenBinary(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None);
                                Logo = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Logo;
    }
```

Comment: O~ thanks, it work :)  So that the `byte[] image= sp_item.File.OpenBinary();` will give me the data of the image?

Comment: Yes. My requirement was to convert image into base64 string.so that i can use it as data url.

Answer (score 2):

First suggestion, as soon as you have the absolute URL of the file in SharePoint, use this:

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("FILE_URL")))
    {
        // Do something with the stream
    }
```

Comment: I cannot use webLient, it brings an Unauthorized error.. I have tried it already.

Comment: Unauthorized indicates that the requested resource requires authentication.

Comment: Use Akshay's code, it will work.